# How to get React.js to accept a POST to a route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio

Building my first React.js app and I can't seem to get the app to redirect.

I am using the Twilio Voice TwiML ([here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-a-browser-based-walkie-talkie-react-twilio-programmable-voice-functions)) inside my React app. I have the frontend and server.

I can record what is said then transcribe it. Then redirect with an `action:` to a URL.

Below is my call.js Twilio function (server). The `/Omg` redirect isn't working.

```js
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    
  const recipient = event.recipient;
    
  twiml.record({
    // transcribeCallback: '/transcription'
    action: '/Omg'
  });
  twiml.hangup();
    
    
  return callback(null, twiml);
}
```

Below is my App.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Omg from './Omg';
import './App.css';
      
const { Device } = require('twilio-client');
    
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    this.state={
      identity: '',
      status: '',
      ready: false
    }
    
    this.onChangeUpdateState = this.onChangeUpdateState.bind(this);
    this.setup = this.setup.bind(this);
    this.connect = this.connect.bind(this);
    this.disconnect = this.disconnect.bind(this);
  }
    
  componentDidMount() {
    const device = new Device();
    
    this.setState({
      device: device
    });
    
    device.on('incoming', connection => {
  // immediately accepts incoming connection
  connection.accept();
    
      this.setState({
        status: connection.status()
      });
    });
    
    device.on('ready', device => {
      this.setState({
        status: "device ready",
        ready: true
      });
    });
    
    device.on('connect', connection => {
      this.setState({
        status: connection.status()
      });
    });
    
    device.on('disconnect', connection => {
      this.setState({
        status: connection.status()
      });
    });
        
  }
    
  // This method sets the identity of the Twilio Device
  // that your device is going to connect to. This
  // example uses hardcoded values so that only devices
  // with the identities friend1 and friend2 can connect.
  // In a production application, this would have to be
  // handled in a much different way. Most likely, the
  // app would have users who are authenticated with a
  // username and password. Their unique username would
  // serve as their device’s identity and they would only
  // be able to connect to device’s owned by users in their
  // friend list.
    
  connect() {
    const recipient = this.state.identity === 'friend1' ? 'friend2' : 'friend1';
    this.state.device.connect({recipient: recipient});
  }
    
  disconnect() {
    this.state.device.disconnectAll();
  }
    
  setup(event) {
  // prevents form submission and page refresh
  event.preventDefault();
    
  fetch(`https://blah-service-2000014-dev.twil.io/token?identity=${this.state.identity}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.state.device.setup(data.accessToken);
      this.state.device.audio.incoming(false);
      this.state.device.audio.outgoing(false);
      this.state.device.audio.disconnect(false);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
    
  onChangeUpdateState(event) {
    this.setState({
      identity: event.target.value
    });
  }
    
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          {
            this.state.ready
            ? <button className="noselect"
                      onMouseDown={this.connect}
                      onMouseUp={this.disconnect}>
                Press 2 Talk
              </button>
            : <div>
                <p>Enter your name to begin.</p>
                <form onSubmit={this.setup}>
                  <input
                    value={this.state.identity}
                    onChange={this.onChangeUpdateState}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="What's your name?"></input>
                  <input type="submit" value="Begin Session"></input>
                </form>
              </div>
          }
          <p>{ this.state.status }</p>
        </div>
        <Switch>
              <Route path='/Omg' component={Omg} />
          </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
       
}
    
export default App;
```

At this point, I am not sure if its a React rookie error or if its something I am doing wrong with Twilio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React is a client-side application, not an HTTP server. It can't accept a POST request because no request will be made **to** it in the first place.

You need to write actual server side code to handle this the POST request and then redirect to a URL that serves up your React application to the browser.

Comment: The tutorial is serveless Twilio. For instance, if you make a request to Twilio for a token Twilio responds with a response. It should send the URL back that your app should direct to. Non of there tutorials show what to do when using action:

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. When you use `action`, or any other URL that Twilio will make an HTTP request to, you will need to use another Twilio Function like your `call.js` at the top of the question. Quentin is right that React is not prepared to accept those requests, so you will need a server side function to handle them.